# Entity VS Id as Parameter

Tags: c#, performance, domain-driven-design

I'm using DDD.

I have the following interfaces:

```
interface ICustomerRepository 
{
    void Disable(int customerId);
}

interface ICustomerService 
{
    void Disable(int customerId);
}
```

The application will work on a WebService.

I wonder, should I use id's as parameter or the entire Customer entity?

What are the pros and cons of each approach?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, the fact is that this behavior shouldn't be on the repository. Behavior should be placed in entities.

However, your application service contract should probably be exempt of domain classes.

e.g.

```
//Application service (runs in a transaction)
public void Disable(int customerId) {
    var customer = this.customerRepository.FindById(customerId);
    customer.Disable(); //execute business logic
    this.customerRepository.Save(customer); //persist the state
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Although the answer provided by plalx is probably the pure way to accomplish this I have also found that a full save may be overkill in some instances.

How about a mixture of the two:

```
interface ICustomerRepository 
{
    void SaveDisable(Customer customer);
}

interface ICustomerService 
{
    void Disable(int customerId);
}
```

Then the code could be:

```
public void Disable(int customerId) {
    var customer = _customerRepository.Get(customerId);
    customer.Disable();
    _customerRepository.SaveDisable(customer);
}
```

This will require one to be very careful about additional functionality since we are explicit about what is persisted.

Comment: Is there any advantage?

Comment: Should one have an aggregate that requires unnecessary data access then, yes, there is an advantage; else I wouldn't be doing it :)

Comment: Isn't that premature optimization? Did you have performance issues going through a full save? I guess it very well depends on the strategy employed for change detection...

Comment: I tend to go with the easy, less code-to-maintain, route if I can.  So I would save the full aggregate whenever I can.  I wouldn't regard it as premature since I usually consider the impact of *not* being explicit before I do something like this.

Comment: Well, "less code to maintain" is not true in your case. You said it yourself, "This will require one to be very careful about additional functionality since we are explicit about what is persisted.". Using an ORM-based repository you wouldn't care about added features in a single save opeartion. You mutate the entity and you save it, that's it. That's less code to maintain to me.

Comment: There is no need in `SaveDisable` method.

Answer (score 0):

Using CudtomerId is a better idea. Because when you pass the Customer entity (usually we use pass by value), it make a copy of it and work with it; Which is by default will be an empty entity.
So, I think your way is the best.

Comment: Customer is a reference type (class), by default it is passed by reference.
But I don't see that as a problem.