# service operation is called with a not found entity

Tags: c#, domain-driven-design, repository-pattern

I am using [Domain Driven Design (DDD)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain-driven_design).

I've the following operation on my application service `IUserService`:

```
public void EnableUser(int userId)
{
    var user = userRepository.SelectById(userId);
    if (user == null)
    {
        //??
    }

    user.Enabled= true;
    userRepository.Save(usuario);
}
```

Should I throw an custom exception?
If yes, where should i put the custom exception in my application structure?

Comment: One unrelated remark, `user.Enabled= true;` is CRUD and shall be `user.enable()`. The application service should have no knowledge of what it means to enable a user. It's also much more resilient to business logic changes.

Comment: Yes @plalx. I agree with you. The code above is just a shorter example than i could do.

Comment: haven't you combined enabling, loading and saving a user here?

Comment: i would pass in the user object, then you can separate out the repository from the concept of enabling

Comment: Please, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28704015/entity-vs-id-as-parameter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your UserService is not equipped to handle the cases where the user doesn't exist, then by all means throw an exception.  I think creating a custom exception would help differentiate between other potential exceptions, in which case how you handle them would be specified in the handler for that exception type.

Where to handle exceptions is kind of up to how your system is designed.  You don't want them to be handled so far up that the context is lost.  For this example, if enabling the user was a result of a button click or other user operation, the event or method that initiates that call should most likely be handling any exceptions that occur if there are issues, and properly notify the user and log what happened.

Comment: Should i put the custom exception classes in my domain layer? like:

Application.Core\EntityNotFoundException.cs

Comment: If the exceptions are something that may potentially cross into other projects, such as the UI layer, then you will most likely want to place them in the most common project that is shared.  If Application.Core contains lots of shared code, then that would be the place to put them.

Comment: UI layer  should not see domain exceptions. What if you want to have an API and React instead of MVC core?

Comment: Yeah, i get that. i would expect depending on the type of UI and how many layers removed from the domain logic would lead to how to deal with any exceptions.  For your api/react ui example, clearly having domain exceptions exposed wouldn't make sense, in this case with a user operation failure, a somewhat generic 500 response could be returned and then the react ui would deal with how to display/manage that error on the operation.  the api layer may be enough to catch domain exceptions and translate that to the 500 response.